# Column specific data inputs

Tags: data

My data is in the form of 6 columns in a notepad file. 
I want to import, only from a specific column,say, the third column into Mathematica in the form of a list, i.e., i want commas to be placed after each data points.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mma.SE! What have you tried?  Have you looked into using [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html)?  You are more likely to get help if you show what you've tried and explain, if necessary, what was unsatisfactory.

Comment: How about importing all data and then using only the third column of your data with `Part` (see Mathematica help)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a tab-seperated dataset like this:

> 2 3   4   5   6   7
>
> 3 4   5   6   7   8
>
> 4 5   6   7   8   9

```
Import["file path", "TSV"][[All, 6]]
```

> {7,8,9}

For comma-seperated data replace `"TSV"` with `"CSV"` (or `"Table"` for space-separated data). As Michael E2 suggested, this is explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html). General information on importing and exporting  is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html).

If you really *only* want the sixth column to be displayed in the notebook (i.e. not linked to the original data import) then put the cursor at the start of the output cell and assign a new variable name to it (e.g. `col6 = {7,8,9}`). Then you can delete the original list. Though this is a lot of effort for minimal benefit..